# How to modify property of radiobutton without using its id tag

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to go through a loop and check the proper radiobutton. I have multiple radio button named `rb` with a color such as "rbGreen, rbRed, rbYellow..."

Here is my code behind: (listColors is a list of strings)

```
 Private Sub selectColor(color As String)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To listColors.Count - 1 
        If listColors(i) = color Then
            Dim rb As RadioButton = TryCast(Page.FindControl("rb" & color), RadioButton)
            rb.Checked = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

While debugging, I got an error because rb is nothing...

Comment: Are you sure the `RadioButton` is part of the actual Page?  If it's within a `UserControl` or template based control (such as `Repeater`) then you need to `FindControl` based on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the `RadioButton`s in question are not actually part of the `Page`, and are instead part of a `UserControl` or template based control (such as a `Repeater`).

If so, then you need to modify your code to use the `FindControl` of the control that holds the `RadioButton`s in question.

If this is within a `UserControl` the easiest thing to do is something like...

```
Me.FindControl("rb" & color)
```